# How to add striplashes onto my php mail script

Tags: php, mailer, stripslashes

customized my own mailing script. php newbie here so please bear with me. here's the code. I just want to add stripslashes onto the subject and the message, and if so wouldn't it remove also the slashes I made with \r\n\r\n?

```
$headers="From: {$email}\r\nReply-To: {$email}"; //create headers for email
$content="Name: ".$name."\r\n\r\nCompany: ".$company."\r\n\r\n
Subject: ".$subject."\r\n\r\n
Message: ".$message;
mail('opps@gmail.com',$subject,$content,$headers); //mail the message;
$success = "Thank you! You're email has been sent.";
#done;
```

Can anyone show me where to put the stripslashes for subject and message? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$email = stripslashes($email);
$name = stripslashes($name);
$company = stripslashes($company);
$subject = stripslashes($subject);
$message = stripslashes($message);

$headers="From: {$email}\r\nReply-To: {$email}"; //create headers for email
$content="Name: ".$name."\r\n\r\nCompany: ".$company."\r\n\r\n
Subject: ".$subject."\r\n\r\n
Message: ".$message;
mail('opps@gmail.com',$subject,$content,$headers); //mail the message;
$success = "Thank you! You're email has been sent.";
#done;
```

Comment: Awesome! It works. Learning new things for an old dog like me. Thanks @Loic.

Answer (score 2):

Follow below code :

```
  "Subject: ".stripslashes($subject)."\r\n\r\n
  Message: ".stripslashes($message);
```